# How to find the vector, cosine and equation of two intersecting lines.

Tags: vectors

I'm working on some summer problems so that I can be more prepared when I go into my class in the fall. (I haven’t learned any of this, but I am trying to become familiar with it.) I found a website full of problems of the content we will be learning, but it doesn't have the answers. I need a little guidance on how to do this problem.

I’m going to do my best to talk through each part and tell you how I think it should be solved!

A line $L_1$ passes through points $P(-1, 6, -1)$ and $Q(0, 4, 1)$.

a. (i) Show that vector $PQ = (1, -2, 2)$.
So, I can see that if you take the $x$, $y$, and $z$ of $Q$, and subtract the $x$, $y$, and $z$ of $P$, then you get $PQ$. But, is there some sort of formula for this that you would use to answer this question?

(ii) Hence, write down an equation for $L_1$ in the form **$r = a+tb$**.
Would this be: $r= (-1, 6, -1) + t (0, 4, 1)$? (I just plugged in $P$ for $a$ and $Q$ for $b$).

b. A second line $L_2$ has equation $r = (4, 2, -1) + s (3, 0, -4)$.
Find the cosine between vector $PQ$ and $L_2$.
I’m super confused on how you could find the cosine of this when all you have is some points? Or, if I draw this out somehow would I find the sides to do the Law of Cosines?

c. The lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ intersect at the point $R$. Find the coordinates of $R$.
Would I use a midpoint formula to discover this? Since $R$ would be in the middle of both lines?

Comment: While I applaud your trying to get a jump on the course material on your own, it seems to me from the series of questions that you’ve been asking that you’re going about this somewhat backwards. You’re taking a collection of specific problems and then discovering bits and pieces of the subject matter that apply to those particular problems. This piecemeal approach doesn’t feel to me like it’s going to give you a real understanding of the subject—you’ll end up with a bunch of disconnected formulas and tricks that might be hard to integrate into a comprehensible whole.

Comment: @amd You’re right! It might be difficult for me to really get a grasp on this material because it seems pretty difficult. I’ve been keeping a notebook of these different types of problems I’m doing and how I go about solving them. For example: How to show that two lines are perpendicular. Then, I write a description & example of how I would complete it. I hope it helps me during the school year! Even if I learn just a few things now, it’ll hopefully make it easier when learning all the material!

Answer (score 1):

For (ai), you're correct. For instance you want to find $\vec{PQ}$, with given coordinates $P(p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_n)$ and $Q(q_1,q_2,\cdots,q_n)$, $\vec{PQ}=(q_1-p_1,q_2-p_2,\cdots,q_n-p_n)$.

However, for (aii), an equation for $L$ in the form $r = a+tb$ is given by $r=(-1,6,-1)+t(1,-2,2)$. To see this, you may draw a picture. Start at point $P(-1,6,-1)$, and traverse along ($t$) the line $L$ in the direction of $\vec{PQ}=(1,-2,2)$.

For (b), we have another line $L_2:r = (4, 2, -1) + s (3, 0, -4)$. This line is in the direction $(3, 0, -4)$. By the formula $$\cos\theta=\dfrac{A\cdot B}{|A||B|}$$which gives you the cosine of two lines $A,B$ (here "$\cdot$" is the dot product), you have $$\cos\theta=\dfrac{3-8}{3\cdot5}=\dfrac{-5}{15}=-\dfrac{1}{3}.$$ You may also do it by Law of Cosines (I guess), but I don't think it would be easy with just vectors.

For (c), yes as ja72 has noted, you have to find $s,t$ such that $L_1=L_2$. You can do it by equating coordinates: $$\begin{cases}-1+t&=4+3s\\6-2t&=2\\-1+2t&=-1-4s\end{cases}$$

Pick any two equations to solve, and verify with the third equation.

Comment: This has helped me *immensely* and I appreciate your time with this. I just had one question! For part b, how did you get the numbers 3,8 and 5? I'm assuming they come from $L_2$ and PQ but I don't know how.

Comment: @Ella The [Dot_product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is obtained by adding up products of each component from $L_2$ and $\vec{PQ}$. Note that we only need the "direction" of $L_2$: $(3,0,-4)$. $|\vec{PQ}|$ and $|L_2|$, in the denominator, are lengths of vectors (also known as [Euclidean_norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm)).

Comment: My advice is the same as amd's: it seems that you're learning the subject in an unorganized way. Try read through an introductory linear algebra book (many suggestions on MSE). This is the best way to start learning the subject. It's quite inefficient to learn by doing exercises/reciting formulae/etc.

Answer (score 0):

For a, (i) and (ii) you are correct. Just subtract components to get the span vector.

For b. you need to use dot product rule that connects the magnitude of two direction vectors and the angle between them. The dot product of $(1, -2, 2)$ and  $(3, 0, -4)$ is related to the cosine of the angle between the vectors

$$ \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{b} = \| \boldsymbol{a} \| \| \boldsymbol{b} \| \cos \theta $$

<sub>A direction vector is the part of the line equation that multiplies the parameter.</sub>

For c. you need to find $t$ and $s$ when $r$ are equal. You try to solve

$$ \boldsymbol{R} =  \pmatrix{-1 \\ 6 \\ -1} + t\,\pmatrix{0 \\ 4 \\ 1} =  \pmatrix{4 \\ 2 \\ -1} + s\,\pmatrix{3 \\ 0 \\-4}  $$

Comment: No, for part ii she should use $b=PQ$ from part i, not $b=Q$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Hi, could I ask why it would be PQ instead of Q?

Comment: Because that is the direction vector. $r= (-1, 6, -1) + t (1, -2, 2)$ gives you the point $P$ when $t=0$ and the point $Q$ when $t=1$ and all other points of the line for the other values of $t$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify. I edited the answer to more specific as to which vectors to use.